# Alternatives to .apply() to increase performance speed

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I wrote a function that cleans the text of a given string.  And I apply this function to a column in a dataframe(~ 1 million records).

```
from cleanco import cleanco
import re
import pandas as pd
import unidecode

def clean_name(text):

     #convert plain text to utf-8
     text = unidecode.unidecode(text)

     text = text.upper()
     text = re.sub('[()]', '', text)
     text = text.replace(',' , '')
     text = text.replace(' - ', ' ')
     text = text.replace(r"\(.*\)","")
     text = text.replace(' AND ', ' & ')
     text = text.strip()
 
     x = cleanco(text)
     text = x.clean_name()
     text = text.replace('.', '')
     text = text.title()
    
     return text

df['name_clean'] = customer_info_df['name'].apply(utils.clean_name)
```

While the function gets the job done, the performance speed seems to be a bit long (~13-15mins) to finish a dataframe of over 1 million rows. Are there any alternatives to increase the speed and effeciency?

Comment: what does cleanco do?

Comment: generally speaking, if you can't use pandas/numpy vectorized operations, you're stuck with `apply`.  You could try multiprocessing, or more exotic performance tools like wrapping your own `C` function, but my guess is the effort/reward is low unless you *really* need performance

Comment: @anon01 the package cleanco helps clean out organization names. https://pypi.org/project/cleanco/

Comment: a tangent to your question but this line will simplify some of your code: `chars = re.escape(string.punctuation) \ text = re.sub(r'['+chars+']', '',text)`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the best solution, but one approach to reduce the time processing is the concatenation of the replace method.

```
import re

text = text.upper()
text = re.sub('[()]', '', text)
text = text.replace(',' , '').replace(' - ', ' ').replace(r"\(.*\)","").replace(' AND ', ' & ').strip()
```

In honor of true, this method takes two subcases performances.

**Case 1:  strings are no-numeric**

**With concatenation**

```
text ='a.b-c.d-d.d.dadad.da-da.dakdapsckcpkepéka´pksXCAKXosñ{xas,x_x.-cda,xa-.-lksslakxslñksaxñlax,-.'
start = datetime.now()
text = text.upper()
text = re.sub('[()]', '', text)
text = text.replace(',' , '').replace(' - ', ' ').replace(r"\(.*\)","").replace(' AND ', ' & ').strip()
end = datetime.now()
```

> start - end = 0.000101

**Original**

```
start = datetime.now()
text = 'a.b-c.d-d.d.dadad.da-da.dakdapsckcpkepéka´pksXCAKXosñ{xas,x_x.-cda,xa-.-lksslakxslñksaxñlax,-.'
text = text.upper()
text = re.sub('[()]', '', text)
text = text.replace(',' , '')
text = text.replace(' - ', ' ')
text = text.replace(r"\(.*\)","")
text = text.replace(' AND ', ' & ')
text = text.strip()
end = datetime.now()
```

> start - end = 0.000202

Comment: How come putting the replace methods all in one line will reduce the time processing?

Comment: Maybe the overwritting of the text = text.replace consume time, because its neccesary the redefinition of the "text string". Another factor is the replace method, as replace is a method, return new value and not affect the "text string"